# Accessing a variable stored within a class Swift

Tags: class, swift, instance, uipickerview

I  can't figure out why I can't access this variable, see below, I want the value of sport result when it's clicked, however sportResult.selectedSport returns nil?

```
let sportPickerData = SportPickerData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

        sportPickerView.delegate = sportPickerData
        sportPickerView.dataSource = sportPickerData


class SportPickerData: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var sports = ["Football", "Baseball", "Hockey", "Basketball"]

    var selectedSport: String?

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return sports.count
    }

    func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedSport = sports[row]
    }

    func pickerView(yearPicker: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return "\(sports[row])"
        }
}

let sportResult = SportPickerData()


@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = sportResult.selectedSport
    }
```

Comment: Have you set delegate to your picker view like `pickerView.delagate = sportResult`

Comment: I set it sportPickerView.delegate = sportPickerData (see edits), is that my problem?  do I need to reset it to my instance of sportPickerData, and that wouldn't impact the operation of the picker?

Comment: Check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sportResult its not a delegate or a data source of your picker view so its selectedSport property will never be initialized since its didSelectRow method will be never called. To get the selectedSport you have to get it from sportPickerData which is actually the delegate and data source of your picker

```
let sportResult = SportPickerData() // delete this line 


@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
    label.text = sportPickerData.selectedSport
}
```

Comment: thank you!  I had added that line because I thought I needed to create an instance to get selectedSport, however the problem was just that I was calling my class SportPickerData.selectedSport (capital S), instead of sportPickerData (lower case s)